# Why SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild does not work with MSBuild 15.0?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I rencently upgraded my Visual Studio from 2015 to 2017.
The build process now uses MSBuild 15.0 so I can use C#7.

I installed a SonarQube server from the latest version 6.3 and I use the latest version of the C# scanner 2.2.0.24.

I'm trying to make an analysis of my code, from the folder where my solution is:

1. Run `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /key:"myproject"`.

   ```
   SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
   Default properties file was found at C:\myfolder\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
   Loading analysis properties from C:\myfolder\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
   Pre-processing started.
   Preparing working directories...
   SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
   11:21:18.714  Updating build integration targets...
   11:21:18.735  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
   11:21:19.341  Generating rulesets...
   11:21:19.39  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
   11:21:19.392  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
   11:21:19.435  Pre-processing succeeded.
   ```
2. Run `MSBuild` version 15.1.548.43366.

   ```
   ...

   Build succeeded.
       0 Warning(s)
       0 Error(s)
   ```
3. Run `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end`.

   ```
   SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
   Default properties file was found at C:\myfolder\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
   Loading analysis properties from C:\myfolder\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
   Post-processing started.
   SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
   The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
   Possible causes:
   1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
   2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
   3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
   Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
   11:22:06.162  Creating a summary markdown file...
   11:22:06.167  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
   ```

I can't figure out why it is failing.

Does the c# sonarqube scanner 2.2 support MSBuild 15.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSBuild 15 is not supported by the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2.

The good news is that we are about to release version 2.3 of the Scanner for MSBuild that fixes this bug. You can read more on the bug ticket [SONARMSBRU-288](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-288).

The release will happen within the first half of April 2017.

Comment: Good news! I'll wait for it :)

Comment: Hi, 
Build succeeded, but getting  following error,

No analysable projects were found.SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report.

sonar-project.properties files are not understood by the sonar Qube scanner for MSBuild. Remove files from the following project root folder.

Post processing failed.

Please help me to resolve this. I'm missing any config file ??